# openGL scaling/rotating (what comes first...)

Tags: ios, c, opengl, 2d

Recently, I jumped in to openGL. Most things have working out quite okay, but I keep banging my head against the wall with this one.

I am trying to rotate/scale an 2D image. I am struggling with the fact it I should rotate first, and then scale, or the other way around. Both ways don't quite work out the way I want.

I have made two short video's showing what it going wrong:

First rotate, then scale
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/992980/rotate_then_scale.MOV

First scale, then rotate
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/992980/scale_then_rotate.MOV

The left image is square, the right image is a rectangle. As you can see, with both methods, something is not quite right :)

The black area is the openGL viewport. When the viewport is square, everything is fine, when it is a rectangle, things start to go wrong :) For every image i draw, I calculate a different X and Y scale, in reference to the viewport, I think I am doing something wrong there...
Note that I am quite new to openGL, and I am probably doing something stupid (I hope I am). Hopefully, I can get my question across clearly this way.

Thanks in advance for any help given!

Corjan

The code for drawing one image:

```
void instrument_renderer_image_draw_raw(struct InstrumentRenderImage* image, struct InstrumentRendererCache* cache, GLuint program) {

// Load texture if not yet done
if (image->loaded == INSTRUMENT_RENDER_TEXTURE_UNLOADED) {
    image->texture = instrument_renderer_texture_cache_get(image->imagePath);

    if (image->texture == 0) {
        image->loaded = INSTRUMENT_RENDER_TEXTURE_ERROR;
    }
    else {
        image->loaded = INSTRUMENT_RENDER_TEXTURE_LOADED;
    }
}

// Show image when texture has been correctly loaded into GPU memory
if (image->loaded == INSTRUMENT_RENDER_TEXTURE_LOADED) {

    float instScaleX = (float)cache->instBounds.w / cache->instOrgBounds.w;
    float instScaleY = (float)cache->instBounds.h / cache->instOrgBounds.h;

    float scaleX = (float)image->w / (float)cache->instOrgBounds.w;
    float scaleY = (float)image->h / (float)cache->instOrgBounds.h;

    // Do internal calculations when dirty
    if (image->base.dirty) {

        mat4 matScale;
        mat4 matRotate;
        mat4 matModelView;
        mat4 matProjection;

        matrixRotateZ(image->angle, matRotate);

        matrixScale(scaleX , scaleY  * -1, 0, matScale);

        matrixMultiply(matRotate, matScale, matModelView);

        // Determine X and Y within this instrument's viewport
        float offsetX = ((float)cache->instOrgBounds.w - (float)image->w) / 2 / (float)cache->instOrgBounds.w;
        float offsetY = ((float)cache->instOrgBounds.h - (float)image->h) / 2 / (float)cache->instOrgBounds.h;

        float translateX = ( ((float)image->x / (float)cache->instOrgBounds.w) - offsetX) * 2;
        float translateY = ( ( ( (float)cache->instOrgBounds.h - (float)image->y - (float)image->h ) / (float)cache->instOrgBounds.h) - offsetY) * -2;

        matrixTranslate(translateX, translateY*-1, -2.4,matModelView);

        //matrixPerspective(45.0, 0.1, 100.0, (double)cache->instOrgBounds.w/(double)cache->instOrgBounds.h, matProjection);
        matrixOrthographic(-1, 1, -1, 1, matProjection);

        matrixMultiply(matProjection, matModelView, image->glMatrix);

        image->base.dirty = 0;
    }

    glUseProgram(program);

    glViewport(cache->instBounds.x * cache->masterScaleX,
               cache->instBounds.y * cache->masterScaleY,
               cache->instBounds.w * cache->masterScaleX,
               cache->instBounds.w * cache->masterScaleX);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, image->glMatrix);

    // Load texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image->texture);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: At least for me the links are not working.

Comment: Same for me. It would be great if you could describe a little more what's happening in the videos. Even if you fix them now, you'll remove the videos from your dropbox eventually. But if you describe them (or insert images), it may still help other people in the future.

Comment: Sorry, dropbox needed a second to upload the videos. They are working now

Answer (score 0):

What framework/library are you using for matrix multiplication?

The thing that needs to come first depends on your matrix representation (*e.g.* row- vs. column-major and post- vs. pre-multiplication). The library you use dictates that; fixed-function OpenGL (`glMultMatrix (...)` *et al.*) was column-major and post-multiplication. Most OpenGL-based frameworks follow tradition, though there are some exceptions like OpenTK. Traditional matrix multiplications were done in the following order:

```
1. Translation
2. Scaling
3. Rotation
```

But because of the nature of post-multiplying column-major matrices (matrix multiplication is non-commutative) the operations effectively occured from bottom-to-top. Even though you do the multiplication for translation before the one for rotation, rotation is actually applied to the pre-translated coordinates.

*In effect, assuming your matrix library follows OpenGL convention, you are doing the sequence of matrix multiplications in reverse.*

Comment: a uniform scale matrix and pure rotation matrix are commutative **if** there are no rounding errors.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: The `matModelView` matrix in this example includes non-zero translation. I know the question's title is only asking about the order of scaling and rotation, but the fact that translation is introduced 4 lines above `image->base.dirty = 0` concerns me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply first of all! It could very well be that I am doing stuff in the wrong order... I looked at this tutorial as a guideline (http://blog.db-in.com/cameras-on-opengl-es-2-x/). This is the c file that handles all the multifications (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/992980/Utils.h). I am not sure if this is column-major, bottom-to-top or anything though :) I'm afraid my understanding of stuff like this is quite limited.

Comment: About the dirty flag. I introduced that to get a bit of a performance boost. In my understanding, the matrix only needs to be calculated once, until something happens again (image is rotated, moved etc etc). That matrix is cache inside the image struct (image->glMatrix).